# how does the interface of surfaceflinger works?

Tags: android, interface, service, surfaceview

where does the sp<> gets defined in the android source code. please answer in terms of surfaceflinger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled upon this question just now, hope it's not too late.
See `class sp` in
`frameworks\base\include\utils\RefBase.h`
`frameworks\base\libs\utils\RefBase.cpp`